# Textarea in WordPress profile not showing after updating

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm adding an extra textarea into the WordPress profile, the issue I'm having is that once saved it won't displayed. I've seen a bunch of posts about it, even copy and pasted it in to my functions and no go, is there anything I am missing here?

**Old code:**

```
    add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'xtra_field' );
    add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'xtra_field' );

    function xtra_field( $user ) { ?>

    <h3>Teacher Information</h3>

    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="teach_year">Year</label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="number" name="teach_year" id="teach_year" min="1" max="7" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'teach_year', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
                <span style="line-height: 42px;" class="description">What year do you teach?</span>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th><label for="class_intro">Class Introduction</label></th>
            <td>
                <textarea type="text" name="class_intro" id="class_intro" rows="5" cols="30" class="regular-text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'class_intro', $user->ID ) ); ?>"></textarea><br/>
                <span class="description">Introduce your class.</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <?php }

    add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'xtra_save_field' );
    add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'xtra_save_field' );

    function xtra_save_field( $user_id ) {
        if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ))
            return false;
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'teach_year', $_POST['teach_year']);
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'class_intro', $_POST['class_intro']);
    }
```

Someone offline hinted at echoing out the author meta, this appears to have worked and I've updated the code.

**New Code:**

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'xtra_field' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'xtra_field' );

function xtra_field( $user ) { ?>

<h3>Teacher Information</h3>

<table class="form-table">
    <tr>
        <th><label for="teach_year">Year</label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="number" name="teach_year" id="teach_year" min="1" max="7" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_author_meta('teach_year', $user->ID)); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
            <span style="line-height: 42px;" class="description">What year do you teach?</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><label for="class_intro">Class Introduction</label></th>
        <td>
            <textarea type="text" name="class_intro" id="class_intro" rows="5" cols="30" class="regular-text"><?php echo esc_html(get_the_author_meta('class_intro', $user->ID) ); ?></textarea>
            <br/>
            <span class="description">Provide your class with an introduction.</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<?php }

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'xtra_save_field' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'xtra_save_field' );

function xtra_save_field( $user_id ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ))
        return false;
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'teach_year', $_POST['teach_year']);
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'class_intro', $_POST['class_intro']);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Textarea doesn't have `value=".."` argument. Instead it holds it's content (i.e. it's "value") between `<textarea>` and `</textarea>`

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea

Comment: That is EXACTLY what I was doing wrong, Thanks for the reference link.